# What has happened to question #411290?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions, 404-not-found

There's [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50523/189165) at Meta Stack Exchange and [an answer to it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071/349538). [First comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#comment119372_51071) under this answer points to the following question:

> Why do people think functional programming will catch on?
> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411290

When I'm trying to open [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411290), I am getting 404:

[image]

Why is that?

If this question was deleted shouldn't I (10+k rep) still see it?

According to the above mentioned comment, 13 years ago (May 25, 2010) this question **has already got 400 total votes**. Which suggests that it was very popular. And makes is complete missing even more weird (?).

Comment: I'd assume it was DMCA'd, or otherwise nuked for legal reasons.

Comment: As indicated in the [MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50967) (linked in the [same comment you reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/119372)) it is "now merged into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36504)." Since there's no visible merge history on the current question. I _assume_ that "merging" in 2010 actually modified/removed things from the database rather than the current system which has tracked history (citation needed for that though)

Comment: Merging at that point was a hard delete as @HenryEcker says. See [Question was *HARD* deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188590/question-was-hard-deleted)

Comment: Here is a web archive of it from 2010: http://web.archive.org/web/20100219073526/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411290/why-do-people-think-functional-programming-will-catch-on/411749

Comment: Thank you! I'd say that your comments, put all together, would formulate a perfect answer to this question. Assuming that it is worth answering such questions. Since asking about one single 13-years old question, such answer would hardly benefit the community.

Comment: too bad we can't dupe close it because the MSE/MSO split left the target on the wrong site

Comment: I strongly suspect @Henry is right, but I have no definitive proof, so not comfortable with an answer. The history records for that post are among the very rare records in the database where the creation dates are out of sequence with the post history row IDs by a significant amount, a situation I can only imagine emerging due to a post merge resulting in hard deletion.

Comment: Duplicates mentioned in that archive (merge targets?): *[Why functional languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36504/)* and *[How can I use functional programming in the real world?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142948/how-can-i-use-functional-programming-in-the-real-world)*.